# How to change snapshot retention number from 25 to 10

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

How to change the snapshot retention policy of an artifact from 25 to 10? As shown in the image, by default Azure will retain the last 25 snapshots for an artifact. We need to decrease this to 10.

[image]

Comment: Your image in no way demonstrates that 25 snapshots are retained. I only see two snapshots in that image, so I don't really understand why you included the image.

Comment: Its just an example Mark Rotteveel, 
I want to show the last line "We retain only the recent 25 snapshots of this artifact", so I've copied only last few last lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You can store up to 30 Maven snapshots in your feed. Once you reach the maximum limit, Azure Artifacts will automatically delete snapshots down to 25. This process will be triggered automatically every time 30+ snapshots are published to your feed. See [Handling Maven snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#handling-maven-snapshots) for more info.

Comment: So according to this document, with the help of Powershell we can delete the versions inside the Snapshot artifact

Comment: The powershell scripts are used to remove the old version downloaded on your local machine. Maven snapshots retention doesn't support changes, which is a known limit. You can also get confirmation from [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/increasing-artifact-retention-number/1010371). To let others who have the similar question with you know it's a limit, it's suggested that you accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!